# Symfony security is granted

Tags: php, symfony

I have controller with annotation `* @Security("is_granted('PERM_MODULE_OUTBOUND_INVOICES_READ')")` and I write test for some action in this controller, create user and loginIn, and when call rout for this action have error

```
Expression "is_granted('PERM_MODULE_OUTBOUND_INVOICES_READ')" denied access.
```

when add role to user `PERM_MODULE_OUTBOUND_INVOICES_READ` still have access denied

when commented tgis and in action check current user is granted have `true`

```
    /**
 * @Route("/manage/new_outbound_invoices", name="new_outbound_invoices")
 */
public function outBoundInvoiceListsAction(Request $request)
{
        $check = $this->get('security.authorization_checker')
        ->isGranted('PERM_MODULE_OUTBOUND_INVOICES_READ', $this->getUser());
```

but with security annotation access denied why not understand
this is my test

```
        $user = $this->user;
    $this->logIn($user);
    //$t = $this->getContainer()->get('security.context')->getToken(); try get token and have null, but in action have user from session
    $this->client->setServerParameter('HTTP_HOST', 'erp.houseoptima.fi.local');
    $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/economy/manage/new_outbound_invoices');
```

this function for LogIn

```
    public function logIn(User $user)
{
    $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');

    $firewall = 'main';
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $firewall, $user->getRoles());
    $session->set('_security_'.$firewall, serialize($token));
    $session->save();

    $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
    $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
}
```

What problem with this security ? With annotation error 403 withot 200 and when check in action is granted user have true

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `User` object

```
/**
 * @Security("is_granted('PERM_MODULE_OUTBOUND_INVOICES_READ', user)")
 */
public function indexAction(User $user)
{
```

Comment: in action I don't wait user, only request

Comment: try add role, for expirement `PERM_MODULE_OUTBOUND_INVOICES_READ` bit still have 403

Comment: which object require the voter of `PERM_MODULE_OUTBOUND_INVOICES_READ`?

Comment: in annotation without object, when test in action with user fron session

Comment: if it require an user object, then pass an user object. what's the problem?

Comment: first I deleted annotation security, then I can enter in action, then I check, for experiment, is granted user from session and have true. Problem with why need annotaion security is granted without object or how work this annotaion

Comment: I want understan `* @Security("is_granted('PERM_MODULE_INBOUND_INVOICES_READ')") and 
          $check = $this->get('security.authorization_checker')
         ->isGranted('PERM_MODULE_OUTBOUND_INVOICES_READ', $this->getUser());`

this is equally check permission functional ?

Comment: It's not the same, no. If your attribute (`PERM_MODULE_OUTBOUND_INVOICES_READ`) require an object (`User`), then you need to provide it. If `$this->get('security.authorization_checker') ->isGranted('PERM_MODULE_OUTBOUND_INVOICES_READ', $this->getUser())` works for you, then `@Security("is_granted('PERM_MODULE_OUTBOUND_INVOICES_READ', user)")` should works as well